# Elastic Search Adding a Script Field vs Adding a new Index field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search.
I have a index field called "actual" which is of float type.
I need a new field "derived" which is derived from the "actual" field after some computations.
E.g derived.value = ((actual.value/120) - 30) x 2
I need desired field in the Elastic Search because,
 - I want to sort Elastic Search results based on the derived.value
 - I want to retrieve the results based on the derived.value E.g. Retrieve only documents if derived.value > 20

I know we could do this using script field in elastic search as well.
My question is, Which would be more efficient based on fetching time?
Either adding a new index field to the elastic search storage or using a script field?

**Update:**
The formula becomes much complex,
derived.value = ((actual.value/a) - b) x (c - d/2)

Here, 'a' can take 6 different values, 'b' can take 8 different values, 'c' can take 12 different values and 'd' can take 3 different values.
If I'm precomputing the values, then i would need additional (6 x 8 x 12 x 3) fields in one document to just retrieve the value without any computation.

But if I'm using script field then i could just pass the current values for a, b , c, d as params while searching and calculate them on the fly.

I have ten thousand documents currently and it's size can grow more.
Is there any other optimistic way to do this, other than having script fields?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the added field for sure. Script needs to be executed per document per search execution which is CPU intensive. In the former , we just need to retrieve it which should be  much faster.

Comment: Thank u Vineeth for the answer. But the requirement is much more complex as you could see from the update of the question.